# SDWebImage setImageWithURL iOS8 crash

Tags: ios8, sdwebimage

I've been using SDWebImage successfully for long. But with iOS8 its crashing when we set image i.e.

```
[ myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"url"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PROFILE_HOLDER_IMAGE]];
```

Is there way to avoid it

Cheers

Answer (score 12):

They have changed **setImageWithURL** to **sd_setImageWithURL** for iOS 8.

Try this new syntax,

```
[myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"url"]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:PROFILE_HOLDER_IMAGE]];
```

Comment: When upgrading SDWebImage to the latest I also had to add the MapKit.framework.

Comment: I really wish they would put things like this in tutorials to update them... just spent 2 hours trying to fix this trivial problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` is deprecated, also you must check if your URL string is not null. Try this approach:

```
    NSString *imageURLString;

    if (imageURLString && ![imageURLString isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    {
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString];
        [myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
    }
```

Also make sure that you use the latest version of SDWebImage.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues arise when using `SDWebImage` with `iOS8` alongside with the crash, even when upgrading to the latest 3.7.1 version. A quick fix I found is to add the `libPods-SDWebImage.a` to the list of the linked binaries of the project (Select your project target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries > click the '+' and add `libPods-SDWebImage.a`).

This is a fix for cocoapods users.